# Next.js: Can't deploy production build; Works in dev; Am I using the async functions correctly?

Tags: next.js

I am trying to create a production build for a next.js project. However I am getting the following error.

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/products". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'productList' of 'data' as it is undefined.
    at ProductTile (/Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/jcrew-take-home-assignment/.next/server/chunks/619.js:39:5)
    at d (/Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/jcrew-take-home-assignment/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:33:498)
    at bb (/Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/jcrew-take-home-assignment/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:36:16)
    at a.b.render (/Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/jcrew-take-home-assignment/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:42:43)
    at a.b.read (/Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/jcrew-take-home-assignment/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:41:83)
    at exports.renderToString (/Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/jcrew-take-home-assignment/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:52:138)
    at Object.renderPage (/Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/jcrew-take-home-assignment/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/render.js:53:854)
    at Function.getInitialProps (/Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/jcrew-take-home-assignment/.next/server/pages/_document.js:599:19)
    at loadGetInitialProps (/Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/jcrew-take-home-assignment/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/lib/utils.js:5:101)
    at renderToHTML (/Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/jcrew-take-home-assignment/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/render.js:53:1145)
errors FetchError: request to http://localhost:8000/category-server/ failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/antonio-pavicevac-ortiz/Dropbox/developer_folder/jcrew-take-home-assignment/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1461:11)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:327:20)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:478:9)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:327:20)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:194:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:159:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:80:21) {
  type: 'system',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED'
}
```

I believe the crux of it is:

Error occurred prerendering page "/products". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

But I can't figure it out—here are the asnyc files in questions:

[product].js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Image from 'next/image'
import Link from 'next/link'

import Swatches from '../../components/Swatches.js'

function Product({ query }) {
  let { defaultColorCode, description, colors, product, price } = query;
  colors = JSON.parse(colors)

  let [productImage, setProductImage] = useState(`/${product}_${defaultColorCode}`);

  const handleProductChange = (productCode, defaultColorCode) => {
    setProductImage(`/${productCode}_${defaultColorCode}`)
  }

  const myLoader = ({ src }) => {
    return `https://www.jcrew.com/s7-img-facade/${src}`
  }

  return (
    <div className="p-10 grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-1 lg:grid-cols-2 xl:grid-cols-2 gap-5">

      <div className="product-link p-2 rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg">
        <Image className="product-image" loader={myLoader}
          src={productImage} alt={description} layout="fill" />

        <p className="font-medium text-sm mb-2">{description}</p>
        <p className="text-sm text-gray-700">
          {
            price
          }
        </p>
      </div>

      <span className="p-3 font-medium text-sm mb-2">
        <Swatches handleProductChange={handleProductChange} defaultColorCode={defaultColorCode} productImage={productImage} productCode={product} colors={colors} />
      </span>
    </div>
  )
}

export const getServerSideProps = ({ query }) => {
  return {
    props: {
      query
    }
  }
}


export default Product
```

The home page:

```
import Head from 'next/head'

import ProductPage from './products.js'

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/category-server/')
    const data = await res.json()

    return {
      props: {
        data: data
      },
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('errors', error)
  }
}

export default function Home({ data }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Category Page </title>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
      </Head>
      <ProductPage data={data} />
    </>
  )
}
```

**Update:**

I wound up updating the `/server/category-server.js` file:

```
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')

const PORT = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 8000
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()


app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();

  server.get('https://jcrew-take-home-assignment.herokuapp.com/category-server', function (req, res) {
    res.json(require('./category'))
  })

  server.all('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res)
  })

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    server.use(express.static('.next/'));

        server.get('*', (req, res) => {
          res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '.next/', 'index.html'));
        });
    
        server.listen(PORT, err => {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log(
            `> Ready and listening on PORT:${PORT} in the ${process.env.NODE_ENV} environment`
          );
        });
      } else {
        server.listen(PORT, err => {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log(`> Ready and listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
        });
      }
```

My `pages/index.js`

```
    import Head from 'next/head'
    import absoluteUrl from 'next-absolute-url'
    import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
    
    
    const ProductPage = dynamic(
      () => import('./products.js'),
      { ssr: false }
    )
    
    const fetchRelative = (req, path) => {
      const { origin } = absoluteUrl(req)
      return fetch(`${origin}${path}`);
    }
    
    export const getStaticProps = async ({ req, res }) => {
      if (typeof (window) !== 'undefined') {
        var res = await fetchRelative(req, '/category-server/')
        var data = await res.json()
      }
      return {
        props: {
          data: data || {}
        },
      }
    }
    
    export default function Home({ data }) {
      return (
        <>
          <Head>
            <title>Category Page </title>
            <meta charSet="utf-8" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
          </Head>
          <ProductPage data={data} />
        </>
      )
    }



And my ProductTile.js

import React from 'react'
import Image from 'next/image'
import Link from 'next/link'

const ProductTile = ({ data = {} }) => {
  let { productList } = data
  var [products] = productList || []
  var { products } = products || {};

  React.useEffect(() => {
    function remove_style(all) {
      var i = all.length;
      var j, is_hidden;

      // Presentational attributes.
      var attr = [
        'align',
        'background',
        'bgcolor',
        'border',
        'cellpadding',
        'cellspacing',
        'color',
        'face',
        'height',
        'hspace',
        'marginheight',
        'marginwidth',
        'noshade',
        'nowrap',
        'valign',
        'vspace',
        'width',
        'vlink',
        'alink',
        'text',
        'link',
        'frame',
        'frameborder',
        'clear',
        'scrolling',
        'style'
      ];

      var attr_len = attr.length;

      while (i--) {
        is_hidden = (all[i].style.display === 'none');

        j = attr_len;

        while (j--) {
          all[i].removeAttribute(attr[j]);
        }

        if (is_hidden) {
          all[i].style.display = 'none';
          is_hidden = false;
        }
      }
    }
    var all = window.document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    remove_style(all);
  }, [])

  const myLoader = ({ src }) => {
    return `https://www.jcrew.com/s7-img-facade/${src}`
  }

  const getColorSwatches = (products, index) => {
    if (products[index] != undefined) {
      return JSON.stringify(products[index].colors)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="p-10 grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-3 gap-5">
        {
          products != undefined && products.reduce((products, product) => products.find(x => x.productId === product.productId) ? products : [...products, product], []).map(({ colorCode, defaultColorCode, now, productId, productCode,
            productDescription, }, index) => {
            let path = `https://www.jcrew.com/s7-img-facade/${productCode}_${defaultColorCode}`
            let swatches = getColorSwatches(products, index)

            return (
              <Link key={`${productId}${index}`}
                href={{
                  pathname: '/s7-img-facade/[slug]',
                  query: {
                    defaultColorCode: defaultColorCode,
                    slug: productCode,
                    description: productDescription, image: path, price: now !== undefined
                      ? now.formatted
                      : 'Not-available',
                    colors: swatches

                  },
                }}
                passHref>
                <div className="product-link p-2 rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg">
                  <Image className="product-image" loader={myLoader}
                    src={`/${productCode}_${defaultColorCode}`} alt={productDescription} layout="fill" />

                  <p className="font-medium text-sm mb-2">{productDescription}</p>
                  <p className="text-sm text-gray-700">
                    {
                      now !== undefined
                        ? now.formatted
                        : 'Not-available'
                    }
                  </p>

                </div>
              </Link>
            )
          })}
      </div>

    </div>
  )
}


export default ProductTile
```

Comment: Looks like the `data` you're passing down to your component isn't defined. Is the request to `http://localhost:8000/category-server/` successful, and does it return the expected result? Also, should you even be pointing to `http://localhost:8000` when deploying to production?

Comment: @juliomalves Hey thanks for chiming, I realized that mistake and now I can deploy it but I get not data and no errors!  i.e nothing renders lol